# deadlock oracle rac from weblogic transactions

Tags: oracle, weblogic, database-deadlocks

Recently a table in my database was in lock. I am using Oracle RAC and transactions sent to the database are managed by weblogic 10.3.0. I have configured the multiple datasources and my transaction has enabled the options "Supports Global Transaction" and "One-Phase Commit". After that table was in lock, I don't why the weblogic don't kill this transaction, my questions here are:

1 - What's the possibles reasons to ORACLE RAC lock the table based on my connection pool configurations?

2 - Why weblogic didn't kill the transaction after the timeout (for this case I have the timeout set with 30s) ?

More Info: I'm using a thin driver to connect weblogic with ORACLE RAC

For this scenario I didn't see error related with deadlock or something like this on logs :(